# Table data Gateway with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns

I have question about pattern Table data Gateway... I´m creating small project, only for my purpose and I want to implement Table Data Gateway pattern. It is possible to use EntityFramework to create data manipulations method like Insert,Update, Delete for this pattern ? and use Data context for connecting to database ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Fowler's examples for Table Data Gateway in [POEE](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html), you'll see that he makes explicit SQL calls in the code and returns a record or dataset. For example:

```
public IDataReader FindWithLastName(String lastName) {
     String sql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE lastname = ?";
```

Since Entity Framework abstracts that work for you I would argue that you're not really using the pattern if you're referencing EF entities. That said, you asked if it's *possible* to do it and of course the answer's yes. It seems to be more of a question of how 'pure' you want to be in implementing the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the Table Data Gateway pattern is to keep the developers from having to write SQL directly and also to allow for centralizing SQL code so the DBA can maintain it easily.

In that way, Entity Framework is at least 50% effective for this.  With Entity Framework, the developers won't have to write SQL code, so you avoid the problem of developers who do not know how to write SQL code.

As for centralizing SQL code for easy administration for the DBA, you can implement stored procedures with Entity Framework whereby you can provide the insert, update and delete methods , which I believe will meet the rest of the requirement.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx) is an article by Julie Lerman that has a video as well as text content that tells you how to map your stored procedures for CRUD.

Comment: Ok thanks, so it is possible these two things combine as I wrote ? :) EF - to CRUD (no sql) and data mapper as a pattern which I want to use?

Comment: I am not certain you're reading the answers you're being given.  A pattern is not a technology.  Patterns are technology agnostic.  I restated the purposes of the pattern, told you that you could use EF to address both of the primary purposes of the pattern and gave you a link to an article telling you how to do the only part that is not provided simply by using EF.  If you are married to a particular implementation of the pattern then those details may keep you from using EF, but I don't believe you have surfaced any concerns that make me think EF would be ruled out as a tool.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has a tutorial on this at: [EF Designer CUD Specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593489)

Comment: Yes, thanks! But it is possible to combine this two things ( table data gateway and Entity framework ( which I only want to use to easy connect to my db) ? .. I must use this pattern...  Thanks !